# Unable to getX and Y for Item withing listItem

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView which contains an ImageView. When the imageView is clicked, im trying to get the X and Y position of it. But it seems to return 0.

Im not sure if the way im referencing the ImageView withing the listItem is right.

**ivX and ivY return 0**

Here is the snippet from the Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{    
    final int temp = position;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
    }

    TextView chapterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView chapterDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    final ImageView listImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final ImageView hiddenImg = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHidden);

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

    if(a==0)
    {
        ll.setAlpha(0);
        a=1;
    }


    //hiddenImg.setImageAlpha(0);

    listImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Imagine Dragons" + " " + Integer.toString(temp), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ImageView ivTemp = (ImageView) v;

            ivX = listImg.getX();
            ivY = listImg.getY();

            Log.i("imageview",Float.toString(ivX));
            Log.i("imageview",Float.toString(ivY));

            ll.setAlpha(1);
            AnimateIt(hiddenImg,ivX,ivY);
        }
    });
```

**listItem.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="CodeLearn Chapter 1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Description" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to be querying:

```
ivX = ivTemp.getX();
ivY = ivTemp.getY();
```

instead, also this will give you the position of **ImageView** relative to the **ListView**.

What do you exactly mean by position of the ImageView? Top Left in pixels, realtive to Top Left of the Screen?

You could also use [**.getLocationOnScreen()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5b%5d%29) method on View object:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
ivTemp.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int ivX = location[0];
int ivY = location[1];
```